# XPath 1 query and attributes name

Tags: xpath, attributes

First question: is there any way to get the **name** of a node's attributes?

```
<node attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" />
```

Second question: is there a way to get attributes and values as value pairs? The situation is the following:

```
<node attribute1="10" attribute2="0" />
```

I want to get all attributes where value>0 and this way: "attribute1=10".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> First question: is there any way to
>   get the name of a node's attributes?
>
> `<node attribute1="value1"
>   attribute2="value2" />`

**Yes:
This XPath expression** (when `node` is the context (current) node)):

**`name(@*[1])`**

produces the name of the first attribute (the ordering may be implementation - dependent)

**and this XPath expression** (when `node` is the context (current) node)):

**`name(@*[2])`**

produces the name of the second attribute (the ordering may be implementation - dependent).

> Second question: is there a way to get
>   attributes and values as value pairs?
>   The situation is the following:
>
> `<node attribute1="10" attribute2="0"
>   />`
>
> I want to get all attributes where
>   value>0 and this way: "attribute1=10".

**This XPath expression** (when the attribute named "`attribute1`" is the context (current) node)):

**`concat(name(), '=', .)`**

produces the string:

**`attribute1=value1`**

**and this XPath expression** (when the node `node` is the context (current) node)):

**`@*[. > 0]`**

selects all attributes of the context node, whose value is a number, greater than 0.

**In XPath 2.0 one can combine them in a single XPath expression**:

**`@*[number(.) > 0]/concat(name(.),'=',.)`**

to get (in this particular case) this result:

**`attribute1=10`**

**If you are using XPath 1.0**, which is less powerful, you'll **need to embed the XPath expression in a hosting language, such as XSLT**. The following XSLT 1.0 thransformation :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*[number(.) > 0]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.),'=',.)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<node attribute1="10" attribute2="0" />
```

**Produces exactly the same result**:

**`attribute1=10`**

Comment: Is FLOWR XPath 2 or would `for $i in @*[. > 0] return concat(local-name($i), "=", $i)` be ok for XPath 1.0?

Comment: @TheConstructor, XPath 2.0 and later versions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit on the context, I believe. In most cases, I expect you'd have to query "`@*`", enumerate over the items, and call "`name()`" - but it may work in some tests.

Re the edit - you can do:

```
@*[number(.)>0]
```

to find attributes matching your criteria, and:

```
concat(name(),'=',.)
```

to display the output. I don't think you can do both at once, though. What is the context here? xslt? what?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the quick answer. Is there any way to get attributes and names as value pairs? Hmm... maybe I should edit my question.

Comment: Today I'm using XFactorStudio XPath 1 library and ActionScript 2.

Comment: Then I believe you're going to have to do the filter and projection separately (as above, or projection as appropriate for the environment).

Comment: It is exactly what I was trying not to do, but of course if there's no way to do anything with a query...